# How is @Array(length= ?) Annotation in OpenHFT/Chronicle-Values Used

Tags: java, arrays, memory-management, chronicle

This question is regarding [Chronicle-Values](https://github.com/OpenHFT/Chronicle-Values)

One example found in the site is:

```
interface SomeStats {
    @Array(length=100)
    long getPercentFreqAt(int index);
    void setPercentFreqAt(int index, long percentFreq);
    long addPercentFreqAt(int index, long addition);
}
```

Here the annotation is only applied to the one of the methods. Does this imply all methods afterwards are treated as working on the array data?

In [one of the test](https://github.com/OpenHFT/Chronicle-Values/blob/master/src/test/java/net/openhft/chronicle/values/HasArraysInterface.java) cases I found

```
package net.openhft.chronicle.values;

public interface HasArraysInterface {
    @Array(length = 4)
    void setFlagAt(int idx, boolean flag);

    boolean getFlagAt(int idx);

    @Array(length = 4)
    void setByteAt(int idx, byte b);

    byte getByteAt(int idx);

    @Array(length = 4)
    void setShortAt(int idx, short s);

    short getShortAt(int idx);

    @Array(length = 4)
    void setCharAt(int idx, char ch);

    char getCharAt(int idx);

    @Array(length = 4)
    void setIntAt(int idx, int i);

    int getIntAt(int idx);

    @Array(length = 4)
    void setFloatAt(int idx, float f);

    float getFloatAt(int idx);

    @Array(length = 4)
    void setLongAt(int idx, long l);

    long getLongAt(int idx);

    @Array(length = 4)
    void setDoubleAt(int idx, double d);

    double getDoubleAt(int idx);

    @Array(length = 4)
    void setStringAt(int idx, @MaxUtf8Length(8) String s);

    String getStringAt(int idx);
}
```

What I understood from this is that you can have multiple arrays within this interface where `@Array(length = 4)` applies to methods ending with `At` until the next annotation. Is this right?

In addition can you have something like the following to simulate an array of 4 double and array of 8 strings:

```
    @Array(length = 4)
    void setDoubleAt(int idx, double d);

    double getDoubleAt(int idx);

    @Array(length = 8)
    void setStringAt(int idx, @MaxUtf8Length(8) String s);

    String getStringAt(int idx);
```

What is the memory layout of multiple arrays allocated with multiple `@Array(length= ?)` within one interface? Can you choose between column oriented or row oriented layout? How will the layouts be handled if the `length` is different?

Also instead of:

```
interface SomeStats {
    @Array(length=100)
    long getPercentFreqAt(int index);
    void setPercentFreqAt(int index, long percentFreq);
    long addPercentFreqAt(int index, long addition);
}
```

can you write it as:

```
@Array(length=100)
interface SomeStats {
    long getPercentFreqAt(int index);
    void setPercentFreqAt(int index, long percentFreq);
    long addPercentFreqAt(int index, long addition);
}
```

implying `@Array(length=100)` applies to the whole interface.

Also can you defer specifying the length until the point of creation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. > Here the annotation is only applied to the one of the methods. Does this imply all methods afterwards are treated as working on the array data?

From [`@Array` javadoc](http://static.javadoc.io/net.openhft/chronicle-values/1.5.3/net/openhft/chronicle/values/Array.html):

> This annotation must be put on a single method accessing the array elements: getter, or setter, or adder, etc.

I. e. `@Array` should be put on *one (any)* method, accessing a field. "Field" is defined by standard accessor methods, and name, i. e. in your example, in the `SomeStats` value interface, there is a single (array) field, named `PercentFreq`. If you add method like `getAnotherField()`, `setAnotherField()` to this interface, it would be a separate field, to which `@Array` annotation doesn't apply, i. e. it would be a "scalar" field, unless you put `@Array` on `getAnotherField()` or `setAnotherField()` and add `int index` parameters to those methods, and `-At` suffix.

2.

> What I understood from this is that you can have multiple arrays within this interface where @Array(length = 4) applies to methods ending with At until the next annotation. Is this right?

No, not "until the next annotation". Annotation is applied to a *field*. Field accessor methods (identified by the field name) could go in any order in the interface definition.

3.

> What is the memory layout of multiple arrays allocated with multiple @Array(length= ?) within one interface? Can you choose between column oriented or row oriented layout? How will the layouts be handled if the length is different?

In your example, layout would be:

```
Double element 0 (8 bytes)
Double element 1 (8 bytes)
Double element 2 (8 bytes)
Double element 3 (8 bytes)
String element 0 (9 bytes: 1 bytes to encode size + 8 bytes of reserved space)
...
String element 7 (9 bytes)
```

To have row-based alignment, your should define another interface:

```
interface Row {
    void setDouble(double d);
    double getDouble();

    void setString(@MaxUtf8Length(8) String s);
    String getString();
}
```

And then define array or rows:

```
interface MyTopInterface {
    @Array(length=8)
    void setRowAt(int index, Row row);
    Row getRowAt(int index);
}
```

This will be equally efficient and take the same amount of memory, as "column orientied" layout. [Read about nested structures in the tutorial.](https://github.com/OpenHFT/Chronicle-Values#another-value-interface)

4.

> implying @Array(length=100) applies to the whole interface.

You cannot do this, use the pattern suggested above (nested interface)

5.

> Also can you defer specifying the length until the point of creation?

No, the whole idea of Chronicle Values is that their size total is statically known.

Answer (score 0):

The Array length is required as the space is allocated in place. When you specify a length of N it means you can  only have indexes 0 <= index < N.